# Check if an awk array contains a value

Tags: arrays, awk

With Perl you can check if an array contains a value

```
$ perl -e '@foo=(444,555,666); print 555 ~~ @foo ? "T" : "F"'
T
```

However with awk, this similar command is checking the array indexes rather than
values

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {split("444 555 666", foo); print 555 in foo ? "T" : "F"}'
F
```

How can I check if an array contains a particular value with awk?

Comment: I believe your only option is to loop.

Comment: Like Etan says, you need a for-loop. You can achieve a somewhat flexible result by creating a new array (hash) with the values as keys, e.g.: `awk 'BEGIN { split("444 555 666", foo); for(i=1; i<=length(foo); i++) bar[foo[i]]; print 555 in bar ? "T" : "F" }'`

Comment: @Thor - Can't you just use `for( i in foo ) bar[foo[i]]` instead?

Comment: @n0741337: You are right, shorter and cleaner, so it becomes: `awk 'BEGIN { split("444 555 666", foo); for(i in foo) bar[foo[i]]; print 555 in bar ? "T" : "F" }'`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Awk noob here. I digested [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26762370/168034) and ended up with this hopefully easier to understand snippet below. There are 2 more subtle problems:

- An Awk array is actually a dictionary. It's not `["value1", "value2"]`, it's more like `{0: "value1", 1: "value2"}`.
- `in` checks for keys, and there is no built-in way to check for values.

So you have to convert your array (which is actually a dictionary) to a dictionary with the values as keys.

```
BEGIN {

    split("value1 value2", valuesAsValues)
    # valuesAsValues = {0: "value1", 1: "value2"}

    for (i in valuesAsValues) valuesAsKeys[valuesAsValues[i]] = ""
    # valuesAsKeys = {"value1": "", "value2": ""}
}

# Now you can use `in`
($1 in valuesAsKeys) {print}
```

---

## For one-liners:

```
echo "A:B:C:D:E:F" | tr ':' '\n' | \
awk 'BEGIN{ split("A D F", parts); for (i in parts) dict[parts[i]]=""}  $1 in dict'
```

Answer (score 0):

what I do is structure my data to take advantage of what the language provides.

So instead of saying :

```
BEGIN {split("444 555 666", foo); .... }
```

say :

```
BEGIN { bar[ "444" ] ; ... }
```

or ala another suggestion:

```
BEGIN { 
  split("444 555 666", foo);
  for( i in FOO ) bar[foo[i]];
}
```

remember arrays in awk are really associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

gawk 'BEGIN { split("a b c d",parts); for (i in parts) dict[parts[i]]=1 } $1 in dict {print}' some.log

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN {
  split("value1 value2 value3", valueArray)
  # valueArray is {1: "value1", 2: "value2", 3: "value2"}
}
{
  # given $1 is the value to test for
  for (i in valueArray) {
    if ( $1 == valueArray[i] ) {
      print $1
      # OR 
      print "True"
      # ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of a one-liner (see Thamme's answer) that sticks more to the OP's `perl` reference (ternary operator):

`echo -e "a\nb\nc" | awk '{t[$1]}END{print (("a" in t) ? "yes":"no")}' # prints yes, try with ("m" in t)`