# check whether elements are present in list or not bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
  : ${models:=foo bar foobar baz}
  : ${special_list:=station_tracks user_features}

   for model in $models;

  do
      echo $model
    if # model in special list; then # how do i test this?
       # do something 
        continue

    fi
done
```

So, basically how do i test whether the variable model is in `special_list` or not?

Comment: See [Check if an array contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8574392/3030305)

Comment: ...though `models` isn't an array here -- it's just a string, which makes it a bit different from that other question -- it *should* be; ie. if this were written according to best practices, it would be an array, and would be a proper duplicate.

Comment: Personally, I'd build `special_list` as an associative array, if its purpose were fast lookups: `declare -A special_list=( [station_tracks]=1 [user_features]=1 )`; then, one can use `if [[ ${special_list[$model]} ]]` to do a membership check in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Perl has the [SmartMatch operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26746361) `~~`. As has [been noted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3685970), Bash and not
even Awk have an equivalent, however you could use grep as a workaround. Also
before I continue, if you are going to use a Bash array, use a Bash array. Your
syntax is going to break horribly once something beyond the most simple example,
like a space, gets involved:

```
models=(foo bar foobar baz)
special_list=(station_tracks user_features)
for model in "${models[@]}"
do
  echo "$model"
  if printf '%s\0' "${special_list[@]}" | grep -Fqxz "$model"
  then
    continue
  fi
done
```

If you prefer you can use equivalent long options:

```
--fixed-strings --quiet --line-regexp --null-data
```

Comment: The "use an array" advice is good; the "shell out to grep" advice... that's a pretty huge performance hit to take. Yes, grep is faster once it's running, but the constant-time startup overhead for the fork/exec will buy a whole lot of O(n) iteration in native bash.

Comment: Heh. I assumed that the outer iteration was needed for some other purpose -- you're right that if it's only being done for the purpose of the join, we're in a different world. (I'd consider using `comm` rather than `grep` in that case, to be eating fork overhead only once rather than once per model).